# Loading Custom Rules into unaccent postgresql hosted into an amazon aws instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-11

The default unaccent module has no or little support for Greek Letters using the `unaccent` module as seen in following links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/49845063
- https://www.postgresql-archive.org/BUG-15347-Unaccent-for-greek-characters-does-not-work-td6035023.html

Also this is my problem in my case as well. So I wanted to load custom unaccent rules as seen in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html

So I wanted to know:

- In the example `CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION fr ( COPY = french );` where the `( COPY = french )` is located?
- Can be the copy statement `( COPY = french )` use data from the STDIN with my own rules?
- Also can I use a dedicated database table in order to load my own unaccent rules as well?

The database is hosted into an Amazon RDS instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *In the example CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION fr ( COPY = french );
>   where the ( COPY = french ) is located?*

Text search configurations are stored in [`pg_catalog.pg_ts_config`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-ts-config.html).

They can also be displayed with `\dF[+]` in psql.

> *Can be the copy statement ( COPY = french ) use data from the STDIN with my own rules?*

No. The COPY clause in CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION clones a text configuration and has nothing to do (besides the name) with the SQL `COPY` command meant to import data from the outside of the database.

> *Also can I use a dedicated database table in order to load my own unaccent rules as well?*

No.

The latest version of PostgreSQL (12) comes with unaccent rules that correctly support Greek (as far as I understand) solving the issue #15347 mentioned in the question. For on-premise PostgreSQL instances, DBAs can get the latest `unaccent.rules` and copy it into an older PostgreSQL version, and making sure that the indexes that depend on unaccent get reindexed. With instances managed by a third party you would have to ask them.